# ASP.NET Core | Compare two Ids from different models in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get specific data by comparing two Ids from different model classes.

I want to get the "DeskId" from the "Booking"-Model class. I don't know how to reach the Booking class from the DeskController.

DeskController:

```cs
[HttpGet("available/{start}&{end}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Desk>> GetAvailableDesks(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var availableDesks = new List<Desk>();
    foreach (var desk in _context.Desk)
    {
        var bookings = await _context.Booking.FindAsync( == desk.Id); /* Compare Booking.DeskId with desk.Id */
        bool available = true;
        foreach (var booking in bookings)
        {
            if ((booking.End >= start) && (booking.Start < end))
            {
                available = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (available)
        {
            availableDesks.Add(desk);
        }
    }
    return availableDesks;
```

Booking class:

```cs
public class Booking
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public Guid DeskId { get; set; }
    public Desk Desk { get; set; }

    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Desk class:

```cs
public class Desk
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Always add code as text, never as image.

Comment: As to your question, it should be something like `FindAsync(x => x.DeskId == desk.Id)`

Comment: @Fildor I already tried that but then he says "The delegate type could not be inferred.".

Comment: After having fixed that, does it still show the exception you mentioned above (delegate type could not ... )

Comment: Yes, it still shows that. But I just use the Answer from Romada Koliada. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to use `.Where` LINQ method:

```
var bookings = await _context.Booking
   .Where(booking => booking.DeskId == desk.Id)
   .Where(booking => booking.End >= start)
   .Where(booking => booking.Start < end)
   .ToListAsync();
```

UPD: As @Young Shun suggested it's better to filter items on db side

Answer (score 2):

Would suggest performing the inner join and filtering operation on the database side.

```cs
var availableDesks = await (
    from a in _context.Desk
    join b in _context.Booking on a.Id equals b.DeskId
    where !(b.End >= start 
        && b.Start < end)
    select a
).ToListAsync();
```

The reason is you are firing *m* time from the `Desk` record(s) for querying `Book` record(s), hence it potentially overloads the database server performance.